# In Apex, what is the order of execution of a delete or undelete?

Tags: apex

In reviewing the Order of Execution of a Save (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm), the document states that "save", in this context, refers to insert, update, or upsert.

Is there a documented set of steps for the order of execution when delete/undelete is issued? I'm particularly interested to know if an implicit save/rollback can occur with delete/undelete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Delete and Undelete go through an abbreviated transaction state. I don't know of any good documentation on this, but it is definitely possible to *block* a delete or undelete from occurring.

Deletes are basically as follows:

Load record from database. Standard validations (e.g. has any child items that would prevent deletion), before delete trigger, temporary commit, after delete trigger, rollup summary fields, parent cascade triggers, etc.

Undeletes is missing a "before undelete" event, but is otherwise nearly the same:

Load record from database. Standard validations, temporary commit, after undelete trigger, rollup summary fields, parent cascade triggers, etc.

It is possible for triggers to explicitly block a delete or undelete, and some other types of actions, like uniqueness constraints, can also cause undeletes to fail.

For example, if you create a validation rule on a parent record that says it must have at least one child record using a rollup summary field, then that validation rule can block a deletion. Similarly, if you specify any error message using "addError" during a trigger, you can prevent deletes and undeletes from occurring.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox (Brian), one question: at what point in the sequence would related objects' references to the deleted object be cleared (these going through an "update" sequence of their own at some point in this deletion process I presume)? Is this what you meant by "parent cascade trigger"?